# Zoomable/Scrollable HTML "window" in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a `<div>` window with inner elements to be able to scroll/zoom on mobile with its contents like here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hk1jfp4z/

I would like to be able to do following:

1. On page load: Scale `#scrollable_zoomable_background` to fit the `#window`.
2. To be able to zoom with two finger gestures, scroll with touchstart, touchend
3. The rest of the page must not zoom, nor scroll horizontally (with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1"/>`)
4. The `#window` must not be an iframe, it needs to be part of the document structure.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, you should to setup your `viewport` to disable zoom the page to user. Then you need to use touch-event library like [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io).

This is standart viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Take a look for a [documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/) of hammer - you can see an example of `pinch` recognizer - that exactly what you need!

Comment: As you can see, the standard viewport I am mentioning in my question. As to using hammer, I would at least appreciate a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Vojtěch I'm so sorry, but my phone can't work with this. I found [this](http://lab.cubiq.org/zoom) example. It's use [iscrolljs](http://iscrolljs.com). So, can you check it, on your device?

Comment: @Vojtěch I tried to work with hammer - but as you know, I can't check it in devices. Please take a look to this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qbeqga) where you can drag with mouse pictures, but I'm not sure about pinch.

Answer (score 5):

Following up on the answer from AleshaOleg, here is a function how you can use HammerJS to implement pinch to zoom -> see pen at http://codepen.io/sheinzle/pen/mebBEd

Obviously there is still a lot to improve - `event.originalEvent.gesture.scale` resets to 1 the next time you redo the gestures. So you would need to keep track of the current scale.

```js
function attachPinch(imgID)
{
    var image = $(imgID);
    $(imgID).hammer().on("pinch", function(event) {
        var el = $(this);
        scale = event.originalEvent.gesture.scale;
        el.css('-webkit-transform', "scale3d("+scale+", "+scale+", 1)");   
   });
}

attachPinch('.pinch-object')
```

```css
.pinch-object {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 5000px;
  
  background-color:#269;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white 2px, transparent 2px),
  linear-gradient(90deg, white 2px, transparent 2px),
  linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.3) 1px, transparent 1px),
  linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.3) 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-size:100px 100px, 100px 100px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;
  background-position:-2px -2px, -2px -2px, -1px -1px, -1px -1px;
  
}
```

```html
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.5/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js/master/jquery.hammer.js"></script>

<div class="pinch-object"></div>
```